# Is it possible to detect if the cursor is over a GameObject with a specific tag?

Tags: unity, c#, input, unity-ui

I've tried quite a few things, but none of them have worked reliably. Here is what I'm currently using:

```
    float scrollInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    // Check if the mouse is over a UI GameObject with the tag "BlockZoom"
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) {
        GameObject go = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
        if (go != null && go.tag == "BlockZoom") {
            // If the mouse is over a UI GameObject with the "BlockZoom" tag, then don't zoom the camera.
            scrollInput = 0f;
        }
    }
```

It works *sometimes*. But obviously, I'm not "selecting" an object.

So is there a way to do this? Keep in mind these are UI elements in screenspace.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it works sometimes"? Under which circumstances exactly does it work and under which circumstances does it fail? How does it fail?

Comment: Are the gameobjects overlapping or always only one?

Comment: Do all the game objects have colliders to detect the mouseover?

Comment: There are overlapping game objects, for testing, I added the BlockZoom tag to eveery gameobject in the prefab, as well as the gameobject with the Scroll Rect component and the gameobject with the Vertical Layout Group. Basically everything up to and excluding the canvas has the tag.

Comment: The UI objects have no colliders.

Comment: "It works sometimes" meaning sometimes it works. It seems to work when I have clicked on something OUTSIDE of the list, but it doesn't work after I have clicked on something INSIDE the list (things with the BlockZoom tag).

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in your mental model here is that the "currently selected object" is not necessarily the same as the same object as the one the mouse cursor is currently on. A game object becomes the "selected game object" when the user interacts with it. For example, a text input becomes the "currently selected object" while the text cursor is in it.

If you want to find out what UI widgets are at a certain screen position, then you have to use [the GraphicRaycaster component](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.html) on your EventSystem. The example code for [the GraphicsRaycaster.Raycast method](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) does *almost* what you want: find out which UI objects are under the cursor (keep in mind that objects can overlap, so you might get more than one result for a single screen position). Now you just need to add a check for the tag.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said "Obviously I'm not selecting an object". It's just the closest code I found that I was able to get sort of working.

Does the raycasting method work for gameobjects rendered in ScreenSpace? I was under the impression it did not.